# Filter on largest value

Tags: tableau-api

I have a field called "ID" which contains integers and I want to create a filter such that I only get a single value, which would be the largest value when I apply this filter.

What are the correct filter settings to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the "Top" condition in the filter settings:

[image]